# Use the smarty variable in smarty project php file

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty project, in a `php` file, I set a `abc` variable:

```
$smarty->assign('abc', '123');
```

now I can use the `{$abc}` in its corresponding `.tpl` file.

but now can I use the `abc` in php file?

I tried `$smarty->abc` and `$smarty->$abc` all can not access.

---

**EDIT-01**

If I use

```
$smarty->assign('abc', '1234');
$abc2 = $smarty->get_template_vars('abc');
```

I will get bellow error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /Users/sof3/Desktop/smarty-test02/php/test.php:36 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/sof3/Desktop/smarty-test02/php/test.php on line 36
```

Comment: You can use `get_template_vars()` function and access variable like this `$abc = $this->get_template_vars('abc'); `

Comment: @Bhavin See my eidt-01, brother.

Comment: Have you `assign()`-ed something to `$this`? I don't think so. You let Smarty know about `abc` by calling the `assign()` method of the `$smarty` object. Use `$smarty->get_template_vars('abc')` to get the value back.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Method_Get_Template_Vars'

Comment: Yeah sof-03. @axiac is right It was my typo use `$smarty->get_template_vars('abc')` like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your Smarty version is version 2.  you can use:

```
$smarty->get_template_vars('abc')
```

but if your Smarty version is 3, you should use:

```
$smarty->getTemplateVars('abc')
```

more detail refer to: https://www.smarty.net/docs/zh_CN/language.syntax.functions.tpl